# Optical Bounds 9-patch disables content padding

Tags: android, android-layout

It seems that setting **layoutMode="opticalBounds"** on a parent layout will disable the 9-Patch content  area. Below screenshot is of a simple TextView:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:orientation="vertical"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:paddingLeft="20dp"
             android:paddingTop="20dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow_with_stroke_gray"
        android:text="lorem ipsum etc"
        android:padding="0dp"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

Whereas the left FrameLayout has its **layoutMode** set to default (**clipBounds**) and the right one to **opticalBounds**.

The 9-patch PNG is also attached to this post.

What is the correct behaviour for this case?

[image: TextView paddings gone]

9-patch image being used:

[image]

Updated 9-Patch image per commentors suggestion:

[image: Updated 9-Patch image]

### Updated with official file from SDK

Using the 9-patch image from the SDL (samples/android-20/legacy/ApiDemos/res/drawable-mdpi/btn_default_normal.9.png) the result looks like this:

[image: Using SDK file]

SDK file (red markers for optical bounds added by me):

[image: 9-Patch from SDK]

The problem remains, the content area is not being taken into account, the text should not draw over the border.

Comment: Did you read https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.3.html#UI ?

Comment: Yes I did read that page a couple times.

Comment: There is patch of your 9-patch image is wrong,
The content patch should not be overlap shadow, but in your image it did overlap the shadow.

Comment: @Concentrated_Attitude yes thank you - spotted that one as well but still same result. Will update the attachment.

Comment: Your padding area is too extended. And your stretchable area too (1px is enough). And the image could be much narrower (You could narrow it to a square)

Comment: @FrankN.Stein yes exactly i wanna tried to said this,
at the scratch sides are left and top, so please use one pixel is enough at these both sides and put the margin at right and bottom sides are for contain.
i did tried same but there there is nothing problem from my side.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein,Yes i agree with Attitude you have just one pixel is enough for left-top side and bottom-right have as much pixel which area you wan to allow to show content.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein,can you please send your original image to my mail ? so i have try to apply 9-patch as per your requirement and send it back to you.

Comment: Alright then. The 9-Patch has been updated. However, the above problem remains.

Comment: The paddings (both vertical and horizontal) are still too extended (no padding at all) - try reducing them by at least 4 px up and down and 4 px left and right. The image is still too wide (unoptimpized 9 patch).

Comment: I found a hackish (?) way to solve the problem by wrapping the TextView in an additional View or Layout and setting the background there.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Actually I don't believe this is the key issue for this problem. To double check I took a file from the SDK (samples/android-20/legacy/ApiDemos/res/drawable-mdpi/btn_default_normal.9.png) and added that. Kindly see the update.

Comment: OK. That one's on me. The `android:padding="0dp"` really shouldn't be there. Sorry everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removed `android:padding="0dp"` and the padding is correct.

Comment: +1 I overlooked the padding=0 issue, which nullifies the padding (you see the SDK has correct paddings on the bottom and right part of the patch).